# PHP regex to get selected string

Tags: php, regex

i have string, it's not really json

EXAMPLE

```
var TEST = { "contextData" :
    {id:01,title:one},{id:02,title:two},{id:03,title:three}}
```

how i can get all title using regex ?

output example : **title:one|title:two|title:three**

Comment: What produced that string? Can you fix it at its source to make it proper valid JSON?

Answer (score 1):

This regex places the `title:[text]` portion in each element, into capture group one:

```
\{id:[0-9]{2},(title:\w+)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/U4_d0e7p1QQU2HQc)